# Apache JMeter 5.6.2 recording doesn't work

Tags: jmeter-5.0

I am using Apache JMeter 5.6.2 For recording. I have followed all steps (activate proxy manuel, import certificat, start test script recorder)
Recording is not happen.

i change configiration. i import many times the certificat. i modify the proxy

Comment: you might have more success on another site like superuser.com as your problem isnt programming related. Also try to include more details in your question, how jmeter is installed/setup, what changes you have tried etc. Good luck!